# Anime with boy who can grow crystals on his body

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've seen a short clip of an anime with a little green-haired boy who apparently can form crystals on his body, like on his palm.

He gets used by an adult (who cut those crystals off) and abuse him until a dark-haired man shows up and saves the boy.

At the end of the clip, he helps the boy to shoot his abuser with a gun. He also gives a white rose to his savior.

Comment: Where did you see the clip?

Comment: On tiktok, the comments were disabled so i couldnt ask

Comment: Have you got a link to it?

Comment: @ShashwatAgarwal - Have you got a link?