# Anime where the MC is a boy who can grow green crystals/gems on his body

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've seen a short clip of an anime with a little green-haired boy who apparently can form crystals on his body, somewhere like on his palm.

He gets used by an adult (who cut those crystals off, probably to sell them) and abuse him until a dark-haired man shows up and saves the boy.

At the end of the clip, he helps the boy to shoot his abuser with a gun. He also gives a white rose to his savior.

I would really appreciate any help given.

It includes this scene:
[image: moment when the adult cuts off a crystal]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It might help if you told us where you found the image.

Comment: I found it in a TikTok clip and on Wechat, but the video is unavailable right now so i can't post it.

Comment: Seems to be the same anime described in this question: [Anime with boy who can grow crystals on his body](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251299/7957)

Comment: Yes, but no one has commented the title so I don't know it.

Comment: If you see the clip on TikTok again, edit your question to include a link to the TikTok video so that potential answers can watch it as well.

Comment: This is word-for-word the same as the previous question; are you the same poster?

Comment: ? What do you mean?

Comment: To save people a little time, the characters in the lower left translate roughly to "Happy Commentary" according to Google Translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***W'z***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%27z) (2019).

> *W'z* is a 2019 anime television series produced by Frontier Works and animated by GoHands. A sequel of *[Hand Shakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_Shakers)*, it aired from January 5 to March 30, 2019. The series stars Katsumi Fukuhara in the lead role, and features music by various EDM artists. From April 10 to 14, a live-action theatre stage was held in Tokyo.

The character who can grow the crystals is **Midori Okuike**. His character description on the Wikipedia page reads:

> Back when he was a child, Midori wanted to help his father's company, so he wished to God for the ability to bring precious metals from the Ziggurat into the real world by tearing his own flesh. Although the Okuike Group prospered, Midori fell ill, as the ability to harvest metals in his body was starting to kill him. Midori's father still attempted to extract the metals from Midori's body until Seba killed him and rescued Midori. In the finale, Yukiya uses a wish to God to heal Midori and give him a chance for a normal life.

I am not sure which episode the image in the question is from, since I have never watched the show.

Comment: This is my duplicate account with the same name & email, anyone can help me recover my old account?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had been looking for this show for more than 2 years but the only clue that i had was a clip that later got deleted, so I appreciate this a lot!! :D

Comment: @MiaoramiaoMiao - if this is the correct answer, please accept it by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows, on the left.